# Error using Spring MVC and Apache Tiles when creates a form controller

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I have the next problem, when i create a form and the controller, the view doesnt render right. The problem is the attribute which wraps the object of the form doesn't work, i think.
The code of the controller is (see below):

```
@Controller
public class IntervalController {

@ModelAttribute("interval")
 public Interval getGreetingObject() {
  return new Interval();
 }


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/behaviour")
public String processSubmit(
        @ModelAttribute("interval") Interval interval, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("interval", new Interval());

    return "behaviour";
}


@ModelAttribute("intervalList")
public Map<String,String> intervalList() {

    Map<String,String> interval = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    interval.put("1", "Day (Calendar option)");
    interval.put("7", "Last 7 days");
    interval.put("14", "Last 14 days");
    interval.put("30", "Last 30 days");
    interval.put("90", "Last 90 days");

    return interval;
}
}
```

And the view which contains the form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="interval">
            <form:select path="intervalName" onchange="controlCalendar()" class="input-large form-control">
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
                <form:options items="${intervalList}"/>
            </form:select>
            <div id="datepicker">
                <form:input id="inputDate" style="display: none;" type="text" path="date"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">  
        </form:form>
    </div>
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/views/jsp/interval.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

....................

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'interval' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.interval_jsp._jspService(interval_jsp.java:157)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:672)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(layout_jsp.java:404)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:167)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please, Can you give me some advises or tips?

Thank you! ;)

Comment: Your controller is never invoked, it will only react to POST requests not GET requests. Due to no controller being invoked, nothing is available. Add a method which returns the name of the view to render and reacts to a GET request.

Comment: Thank you! It works, i create a GET request and initialice the form.